# Is there a way to put the drop down list inside labelframe?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am having trouble with inserting the dropdown list inside the label frame widget? Is there a way to get this done.

I tried coding them separately and running it and then it works but I want them inside.

```
labelframe = LabelFrame(news_window, text="This is a Label")
labelframe.pack(fill="both", expand="yes")

variable = StringVar(news_window)
variable.set("0") # default value

left = OptionMenu(news_window, variable, "1", "2", "3","4","5","6","7","8")
left.pack()
```

I do not get any errors messages but the label frame is not being shown

Comment: Your code runs fine and I can see all widgets being shown. However you might want to change your optionmenu to `left = OptionMenu(labelframe, variable,...)` if you want the menu to be inside the label frame.

Comment: Hi, thank you, it worked :)